# How can i change the parent form lookup value

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

when i open potencial customer from existing opportunities and then just change the value of first name or last name then the change also reflect in the potencial customer lookup in Opportunities entity so i have written a script in onsave of Contact Entity.

```
function getname()
{
    var lookupValue = new Array();
    lookupValue[0] = new Object();
    lookupValue[0].id = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
    lookupValue[0].name = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("firstname").getValue()+" " +Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("lastname").getValue();
    alert(Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("firstname").getValue()+" " +Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("lastname").getValue());
    lookupValue[0].entityType = "Contact";
    window.top.opener.Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("customerid").setValue(lookupValue);
            window.top.opener.Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("name").setValue(Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("firstname").getValue());

}
```

if you look at the above code then you will find that i have set the value of parent look up but it didnt work i have change the value of textbox Topic (name) of opportunities so it will work for me but i dont know why it didnt work in lookup.

if you look at my above code you will find one line    window.top.opener.Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("name").setValue(Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("firstname").getValue()); and this one is work perfectly but it didnt work in look up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preamble: this kind of code is unsupported.

If you want to make it works you need to change only the `name` property, because `id` and `entityType` will not change (at least with the behavior you described)

Is better also to add a check if there is the field inside the opener:

```js
function getname()
{
if (window.top.opener.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("customerid") != null)
{
    var previous = window.top.opener.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("customerid").getValue();
    previous[0].name = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("firstname").getValue() + " " + Xrm.Page.getAttribute("lastname").getValue();
    window.top.opener.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("customerid").setValue(previous);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lookup objects will always display the primary attribute for the related entity.  You cannot change that.  So I'm not surprised that trying to set that value is not working.  It never will.

What is it you are trying to achieve?  Why would you want to change the display in a lookup to not represent the record it is linked to?

Comment: :Let me explain you..For example if you look at the opportunity Entity you will find lookup potential customer Now when you click on the value of it another form will popup and that will be contact form Now my requirement is that when you change the value of first name or last name of contact that should reflect in look up of opportunity rather than refreshing the screen of opportunity entity form.so i have to access the parent form..

Comment: Aah.  OK.  I see now.  It's the refreshing of the data on the opp form that you wanted to deal with.